# C error: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]

Tags: c, cs50

I am writing a function to validate if the strlen of a string = 26 or not and returning a boolean value however I get an error message stating "error: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]" despite there being no way for a value not to be returned. (i have tried it with just else instead of else if and get same error)

```
bool ValidateLength(string key, int argc)  
{
    if (strlen(key) != 26)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        printf("Key must consist of 26 alphabetic characters.\n");
        return false;
    }
    else if (strlen(key) == 26)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just `return true` instead of the whole extraneous `else if` block.

Comment: `"(i have tried it with just else instead of else if and get same error)"` -- I strongly doubt that this statement is correct. On both gcc and clang, the warning disappears if you change `else if (strlen(key) == 26)` to simply `else`. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: The C language does not have type named `string`.

Comment: @ndim: It is declared in the `"cs50.h"` header as `typedef char *string;`, and this function is part of a program to implement a substitution cipher.

Comment: @ndim: Yes, but the question is tagged `cs50`, which probably means that OP is using `#include <cs50.h>`, which contains the line `typedef char *string;`.

Answer (score 4):

Although GCC is able to analyze the code and determine that exactly one of the cases is executed (as shown in the supplement below), presumably this analysis occurs only later in the compilation process. During the initial analysis, the code nominally contains three code paths. Three potential reasons for issue the warning (elevated to an error) in spite of this come to mind:

- Due to the way the compiler is constructed, warnings are generally reported early, and suppressing this warning based on later analysis would be difficult.
- It was deemed useful to report this warning as it typically results from inadvertent program design rather than intentional coverage of all cases with a redundant test. (Experienced programmers will generally use a solitary `else` for the last case, although cases like this could arise from various forms of conditional compilation.)
- The opportunity to suppress the warning was overlooked.

Nonetheless, this is easy to work around. The code can be rewritten as either:

```
bool ValidateLength(string key, int argc)  
{
    if (strlen(key) != 26)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        printf("Key must consist of 26 alphabetic characters.\n");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

or:

```
bool ValidateLength(string key, int argc)  
{
    if (strlen(key) != 26)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        printf("Key must consist of 26 alphabetic characters.\n");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Although you report testing the former option, GCC will not report the warning in this case, so I believe your test was faulty, such as compiling code other than what you intended to compile.

### Supplement

Arguably, this is a shortcoming in the compiler. Looking at [the assembly GCC 11.2 generates for this with `-O3`](https://godbolt.org/z/4boaT9bv5), we see it has in fact recognized that the union of all cases in the `if` and `else if` covers all possibilities: It has generated only two code paths, not three. It calls `strlen` once and either jumps to `.L1` or falls through to the “then” code, which rejoins at `.L1`. Both paths return a value. So GCC knows there is no possible control path that does not return a value, but it reported the warning (elevated to an error) anyway.

Further, [testing by changing the function return type to int and changing the returns to `0` in the “then” code, `1` in the “else if” code, and `2` outside that](https://godbolt.org/z/Kdxo7anfv) shows assembly code that only returns 0 or 1, proving GCC was not just collapsing the third path into “undefined behavior”; it outright eliminates it because it is not possible.

Comment: FWIW, compiling the example code on godbolt.org with `clang` shows the very same behaviour regarding the `-Wreturn-type` as `gcc`.

Comment: IMO warning has to be generated as `key` is side effect prone (GCC optimizes the second `strlen` but warning has to be issued anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Your block if/else if is overconstrained....

Have you tried this ?

```
bool ValidateLength(string key, int argc)  
{
    if (strlen(key) == 26)
        return true;

    printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
    printf("Key must consist of 26 alphabetic characters.\n");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid many return statements in your code. One is enough. It makes code less human error prone.

```
bool ValidateLength(string key, int argc)  
{
    bool result = key ? strlen(key) != 26 : false;
    if (result)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        printf("Key must consist of 26 alphabetic characters.\n");
    }
    return result;
}
```

in your code compiler does not know if the `key` will not be changed in the call to `strlen` as you pass a pointer (side effects). So it does not know if the second `strlen` will return the same value as the first one.

Comment: The compiler does know that `key` (and what it points to) will not be changed between the `strlen` calls. The code generations I showed prove that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil but compiler does not know if `strlen` will not change it.

Comment: Yes, it does know. We know it knows for two reasons. One, the C standard specifies the behavior of `strlen` and allows a compiler to assume any use of it with external linkage refers to the standard library `strlen`. Two, the generated assembly I linked to shows GCC only calls `strlen` once, which it could not do if `strlen` could change the data so that the second call could return a different value.